# nullable keyword with double pointer

Tags: objective-c

In a method declaration, I understand that you can define a double pointer where both pointers can point to null using the underscored `_Nullable` keyword as such:

```
- (void) foo:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
```

Is there any way to do this using the non-underscored `nullable` keyword instead?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple. No it is not possible to use the `nullable` keyword with double pointers and the underscored syntax must be used instead.

Doc can be read here https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes as @Sulthan very well shared in a comment

Not underscore syntax `nullable` and `nonnull` are attributes that apply to properties and parameters and return types of methods and functions, but underscored keywords (`__nonnull` `_Nonnull`...) are type qualifiers that defines the types of each pointer individually so they can be used in double pointers.

Comment: i don't understand why this is not considered an answer. The question asks if its possible to use nullable keyword and the answer is no, it is not possible.

Comment: I see, your edit makes it a much better answer than before. It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers as you did in your edit.

Comment: `nullable` and `nonnull` are not macros, they are Obj-C attributes.

Comment: by the way, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes